# Show header permalink on hover (pelican)

Tags: jinja2, restructuredtext, pelican

How do I get a clickable "permalink" to show on hover (for e.g. `h2` headers) similar to [this](https://www.writethedocs.org/guide/writing/reStructuredText/#why-use-restructuredtext).

I'm using the pelican framework and am writing in restructuredText. I can't figure out where in the stack to tweak to enable this (pelican? rst? jinja2?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a label. Usage is documented under the [`ref` role](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#ref-role).

> To support cross-referencing to arbitrary locations in any document, the standard reST labels are used. For this to work label names must be unique throughout the entire documentation. There are two ways in which you can refer to labels:
>
> If you place a label directly before a section title, you can reference to it with :ref:`label-name`. For example:
>
> ```
> .. _my-reference-label:
>
> Section to cross-reference
> --------------------------
>
> This is the text of the section.
>
> It refers to the section itself, see :ref:`my-reference-label`.
> ```

**Edit**

For Pelican, there is a plugin called [`headerid`](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-plugins/tree/master/headerid) that will render permalinks.

Comment: I see that it will add a `<span id="my-reference-label"></span>` just before the `h2` header, and I can add links to it from other parts of the page. However, how do I allow *visitors* of the page to right-click and get a link to it?

Comment: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_add_permalinks

Comment: Thanks! .. except that I'm using pelican, and not sphinx. Based on the fact that this is implemented in sphinx, I think I  need to look for the equivalent in pelican (which uses docutils).

Answer (score 0):

You can get that through the options of the [Markdown TOC extension](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/toc/#usage).

Just set the `permalink` option to `True` in your pelicanconf.py:

```
MARKDOWN = {
  'extension_configs': {
    'markdown.extensions.toc': {'permalink': 'True'}
  }
}
```